# make scripts run only one instance when a user logs in

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

I am trying to run a few bash scripts continually when I am logged in to my Linux Mint install. Adding them to startup applications doesnt appear to work, because they are not always running when I check. I also dont want to create multiple instances of the scripts so adding them to my .bashrc or a cronjob seems to be out. Any other suggestions?

An example script (warns me when my battery is below 30%):

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
#echo "starting script: $(date)">>battery_log

percent=$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0| grep -E "percentage" | grep -o '[0-9]\+')
cpu_temp=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp | awk '{print "deg C: "$1/1000}')
discharge=$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0| grep -E "state")
is_discharging=$(echo $discharge | grep -c discharging)

#echo "$percent"
#echo "$cpu_temp"



#echo hello | grep -c he
#if [echo $discharge | grep -c discharging -gt 0 ]; then
    #echo "success"
#fi

#echo "$discharge"
if [ "$is_discharging" -gt 0 ]; then 
    echo "---discharging: $(date)">>battery_log
    if [ "$percent" -lt  30 ]; then 
        #exec 2>>/home/king/Scripts/battery_log.txt
        export DISPLAY=:0
        #export XAUTHORITY=~otheruser/.Xauthority
        #kdialog --msgbox "$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0| grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage") \n cpu temp:      $(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp | awk '{print "deg C: "$1/1000}')"
        kdialog --title "Low Battery" --passivepopup "$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0| grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage") \n cpu temp:      $(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp | awk '{print "deg C: "$1/1000}')" 20
    fi
fi

sleep 300 #5min
done
```

Comment: Take a look at `flock`, which can be used to synchronize script execution. You could also use any other atomic operation like `mkdir`. If the `mkdir` succeeds, your script may proceed; otherwise it should terminate. This way you can ensure that only one instance of your script is running at any given time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you run the script, check if an instance of your script is already running.

`pgrep script.sh`.

If it's already running, then you can exit, otherwise continue the script.

`pgrep script.sh && exit` should do the trick.